# Proof regarding $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ as a partially ordered set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a partially ordered set and each $\emptyset \neq A' \subseteq \left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ has a minimal element, then $A$ is finite.
I need to prove that without the Axiom of choice which is pretty hard.
I tried to assume by contradiction that $A$ is infinite, and find a non empty subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ without a minimal element but I didn't manage to work it out.

I would love to get some help!

Comment: "Evere infinite set is Dedekind infinite" is much weaker then Choice - can we use that?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen unfortunately, not. I am sorry

Comment: @Hagen: No choice is needed here. This was one of my favourite homework questions back when I was teaching in Israel. It's also a good introduction to the notion of well-founded relations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Suprisingly... I study @ HUJI

Comment: Well, this is my legacy for you, then. I used to TA the course through my PhD a few years ago.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks alot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you already know that the union of two finite sets is finite.

Tarski's original formulation was actually in the opposite: if every non-empty subset of $\mathcal P(A)$ has a maximal element, then $A$ is finite. This is the same as the minimal version (which is more educational, since we can introduce well-foundedness).

The two formulations are clearly equivalent: replace each set by its complement, and you've reversed $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

But the maximal version is somehow more immediate. Simply look at $\{A'\subseteq A\mid A'\text{ is finite}\}$. If there is a maximal element, it has to be $A$ itself (why?).

Using this idea, and Brian's hint, I'm sure you can solve this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is infinite, consider $\{S\in\wp(A):S\text{ is infinite}\}$. Remember, you don’t need to find a descending chain: you just need a subset of $\wp(A)$ with no minimal element.

Comment: Could you please elaborate furthermore?

Comment: @vpam: I added a little to my answer. In addition, I’ll point out that you don’t need the axiom of choice to pick **one** element from an infinite set.